# Is there a scalable function in Excel that does the same as nesting IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH) functions?

Tags: excel, string, if-statement, excel-formula, vlookup

I am trying to find a better way to search for specific strings in each cell of a column of categories, and then classify those categories together based on which strings are found inside them.

[image]

The column 'Advertisement' contains the different categories and the column 'Trees + Cars' is the result column which extracts 'Trees', 'Cars' and classifies categories missing those strings as 'Other'.

If this were a case of looking for one string only, I could use an IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH) statement. But I realise that if I were to do so for >1 category, I would have to start nesting per category if I were to continue to use IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH) statements.

Is there a more scalable function suited to handling many categories?

Comment: Will there always just be one category per cell, or can there be multiple and what should we do about that?

Comment: When posting sample data, please post it _as text_, so we can copy paste it.  Feel free to also post an image if you feel that adds additional value.

Comment: @ScottCraner for this example, lets assume that each cell will only contain one category and there won't be any conflicts where a cell will try to pick up both trees and cars.

Comment: @chrisneilsen Noted, I didn't have access to images since my reputation needs to be 5 to post images. Definitely will post as text though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can take out conditions in a separate column and index them, you can use the following formula:

```
=OFFSET($D$2;SUMPRODUCT(--ISNUMBER(SEARCH($D$2:$D$5;A2));$C$2:$C$5);0)
```

[image]